Ubuntu 24.04 Thunderbolt Displays do not wake up after OS sleep
I'm experiencing a problem with the following case:

hardware configuration: Thinkpad X13 2-in1 Gen 5 connected via Thunderbolt to the HP Dock G2 with 2 external displays,
putting the X13 into sleep mode and waking it back causes the desktop to extend, but external displays do not wake up - they remain black and suspended.

Before sleep, everything works fine.
I can handle the problem by unplugging and re-plugging the Thunderbolt cable to re-detect external displays, which works fine. However, that is required every time I put the laptop into sleep mode and is inconvenient.
I didn't experience this problem on Ubuntu 22.04.
Any hints on how to troubleshoot it are more than welcome.
